# Create an INSERT SQL query based on other queries

Tags: sql

I need to perform an `INSERT` query like this:

```
INSERT INTO Clients (ClientName, CountryID) VALUES ("STYLUS", 4)
```

But:

- Only insert if `ClientName` (STYLUS for the example here) does not already exists
- The CountryID (4 for the example here) must be retrieved from another query: `SELECT CountryID FROM Countries WHERE CountryUK = 'FRANCE'`

Is it possible to build a single SQL Query for all of this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question correctly.

Comment: Add a unique constraint to avoid insertion of duplicated products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first condition, you need a unique index/constraint on the table:

```
create unique index unq_clients_clientname;
```

Then, you can insert the value doing:

```
insert into clients(clientname, countryId)
    select 'STYLUS', countryid
    from countries
    where countryuk = 'FRANCE';
```

This will return an error if you attempt to insert a duplicate value.  If you don't want an error, then a database-independent method is:

```
insert into clients(clientname, countryId)
    select 'STYLUS', countryid
    from countries
    where countryuk = 'FRANCE' and
          not exists (select 1 from clients c2 where c2.clientname = 'STYLUS');
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Being Simple,

```
if not exists(select * from Clients  where Cientname='Stylus') begin insert into Clients select 'Stylus',Countryid from Countries  where countryname='France' end
```

will do the work.Hope It helps.